# Are Windows 10 retail key revokable?

Tags: windows-10, product-key

The company I work in gives all developers a Visual Studio Professional subscription. This offer includes numerous advantages (Devops, Azure, Visio, SQL servers, etc.) as well as **a whole bunch of retail Windows 10 product keys**.

[image]

If I use one of the keys on a personal machine at home, would my company be able to revoke my Windows 10 license if I were to end my contract (and my Visual Studio subscription with it) ?

**Are Windows 10 retail key revocable ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are Windows 10 retail key revocable?

Windows 10 keys can only be revoked by Microsoft.  However, Microsoft is not going to invalidate a key, because a single employee used the license key outside the terms of the agreement.

> if I were to end my contract (and my Visual Studio subscription with it) ?

The company can indeed invalidate your access to your Visual Studio subscription by simply revoking your access to the account.  If the account is a personal account and is linked to the subscription, this means they would disassociated your account, from their subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! What I meant by _and my Visual Studio subscription with it_ is that if I were to leave the company, that would imply the cancellation of my subscription, but I was wondering if that would lead to the invalidation of the W10 license (which doesn't seem to be the case).

Comment: @AtomicZeitgeist - Microsoft is not going to invalidate a license key because an employee leaves a random company.  If they had that policy, their entire company would spend every waking hour, trying to catch up on the backlog of work that would bring.  If a license key is being used to pirate Windows 10, and it's being used by millions of installations, only then they might blacklist that key (certainly was the case with Windows XP licenses 16 years ago.